# Mail not sent using Laravel & Mailgun on production

Tags: laravel, mailgun, laravel-horizon

I am using a `Mailable` with `ShouldQueue` and the `Queueable` trait. When triggering the mail on my local machine, the mail get sent. However mails are not sent, using the same *Mailgun* env in production. Since my Mail is queued, I have tried using both `sync` and `redis`. On my local machine, both these work, but again, neither do on production.

I have added `\Log::info("Building mail");` to the `build()` method in the Mail. The message is logged, and using *Laravel Horizon* I have checked that the job is being fired. However, no mail is sent to *Mailgun* (checking the logs, not only the actual mail). I have also cleared the config cache to ensure nothing is wrongfully cached.

What seems to be the problem here? Could it be some kind of firewall issue? No error is provided in the logs, nor by Horizon. The production server is on *Laravel Forge* and I have used [this guide by Chris Fidao](https://serversforhackers.com/scaling-laravel/forge) while setting up my servers.

Comment: Have you configured your from email? If your from email address (`config/mail.php:from.address`) isn't set up in mailgun then it will reject your emails.

Comment: Yes, it is set up. I am using the same config/env vars locally. Wouldn’t this result in an error, in either Mailgun or Laravel?

Comment: No, in this specific situation -- if you send an invalid from address to your mail provider -- it can fail without an error, it's a shortcoming of Laravel, and depending on your mail provider, they may not log the error either.